# mirror/auto populate a section of text in another location in the same buffer/other file

Tags: org-mode, text-editing

Im looking for a way to to mirror/auto populate a section of text in another location in the same buffer and/or other file.

for example, i manage my config files in org mode for multiple machines. i want to have a section like this

```
#+BEGIN_SRC conf :mkdirp yes :tangle ~/machine A
CODE
#+END_SRC
```

where the same content of CODE is mirroed/auto generated in another code block for machine B

```
#+BEGIN_SRC conf :mkdirp yes :tangle ~/machine B
CODE
#+END_SRC
```

is this in anyway possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "*mirrored/auto generated*"?

Comment: hi. i mean have the same code in a org code block or .el file appear again identically in another section of a buffer and/or another file

Comment: This answer is probably a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328515/iso-transclusion-in-emacs-org-mode/15352203#15352203

Comment: An established term for this is transclusions. Here's a long summary of discussions of the topic: https://github.com/nobiot/org-transclusion